# iPad orientation not being returned correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm basically running this code:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation statusBarOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

if(statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
     NSLog(@"orientation is portrait");
}
```

However, regardless of the actual orientation in the simulator or my iPad, it is printing "orientation is portrait". Trying to NSLog the statusBarOrientation as a %d also returns 1 no matter what the orientation.

I've stuck this is my app delegate, my view controller, and the class that I need it in, and its the same thing. All 4 device orientations are supported in my info.plist / target settings.

Does anyone have a sure fire way of figuring out the interface orientation, or why mine is not working? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can REGISTER FOR notifications on orientation changes:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];   
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                            selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                            name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" 
                            object:nil];

- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
{   
   UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if ((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {
         // DO STUFF
}
else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
          //DO MORE STUFF 
}

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. For some reason this code actually works on view load. This will help immensely. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

if you dont like to used Notification for orientation.. Then use below method too.

this is example of Only Landscape Orientation in iPad and Portrait in iPhone...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
    {
        if(interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||  
         interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
            return YES;
        else
            return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are returning the orientation of the status bar. Instead get the orientation of the device: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying this code but it doesn't seem to work.

if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])){ NSLog(@"we are landscape"); }

Thanks

Comment: Does your viewController return YES for: `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`